# how do I make my javascript program to ask user to hit any key to exit?

Tags: key, any, hit

I'm new to javascript and I need help. I'm currently doing a project using javascript in which I'm tasked with creating some code which asks the user to hit any key to exit the javascript program. does anybody know how I can do this?

I've tried  using the addeventlistener to detect user input but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Edit: I’m supposed to ask the user to input any key to exit the JavaScript program after it translates a number to the chosen language.

Comment: Hi, can you share the code you tried?

Comment: I've tried something like this but I think it doesn't seem to work. // Add event listener on keydown
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  var name = event.key;
  var code = event.code;
  // Alert the key name and key code on keydown
  alert(`Key pressed ${name} \r\n Key code value: ${code}`);
}, false);

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is part of my code, where should I place the hit any key to exit?  const language = prompt("Choose a language - german or french");
console.log(language);
    if(language === "french") {
        
  return ("Your french translation is: "+germanTranslation[yournumber]);
    }
    else if(language === "german") {
  return("Your german translation is: "+germanTranslation[yournumber]);
    }
        
    else {
        alert("Please enter a valid language(german or french).");
  
  return;
    }    
}
//This calls the translate function. 
translate();
//End of the code.